# Testing data for regular oscillations

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, autocorrelation, signal-processing, fourier-transform

This is a little hard to explain, but I would like to test data for periodic oscillations, but not necessarily oscillations of the same amplitude. for example (crudely!):

[image]

So basically I want to test whether something is happening periodically, but not necessarily the same thing. I'm not too sure how to approach this; I don't think autocorrelation is appropriate given the potential differences in oscillations. Perhaps look at frequencies in the Fourier domain?

[In case anyone's wondering - I'm not Banksy]

Comment: Just an uninformed guess, maybe rainflow cycle counting algorithm can help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainflow-counting_algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two most obvious options are spectral analysis and autocorrelations. In fact, they're very related concepts. The autocorrelation process such as $y_t=c+\phi y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ would imply certain spectrum. See, for instance, Yule-Walker estimation of spectral densities.

Historically, autocorrelation was used for finite samples initially. The reason is that spectral analysis, such as Fourier, assumes that infinite series. Whenever you have short series at low frequencies Fourier analysis will have artifacts from both sampling frequency and the sample size. In these cases autocorrelation approach, such as Yule-Walker, will behave better.

Here, I'm lumping wavelet analysis with Fourier into the spectral analysis. Wavelets can work better when shape of your waves is very different from typical sine waves, for which Fourier is best suited, but you have to pick the appropriate wavelet pattern.

So, I would suggest starting with the simplest tools of exploratory analysis such as periodograms and correlograms. They'll give you an idea of the possible frequencies in the data, at least the lower frequencies.

There's also a technique that I used to employ in astrophysics data, but forgot what is its name. Imagine you have your plot on a transparency. You cut your plot into pieces, then stack them on top of the other, so that you see all parts overimposed on each other. You loop through different number of cuts, and if there's a repeating pattern it'll emerge in one of the cuts. It's very similar to correlogram but it's more visual.

Here's the example. I have the periodic wave, and added the noise and also the change in the amplitude. The graph in the middle shows the stacked cuts at the periodicity of the sine wave, while the graph on the bottom is some other periodicity. In the middle you see that there's some kind of pattern. I used to work with light intensity coming from the stars. When the stars rotate, the intensity may change. So, we tried to detect the rotation speed by detecting the periodicity of light.
[image]

The MATLAB code:

```
rng(0)
t=1:0.1:40;
x=sin(t').*(1+sin(t'/pi))+randn(size(t'))/3;

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x,'.')

subplot(3,1,2)
p=round(2*pi/0.1);
k=floor(length(x)/p);
m=reshape(x(1:p*k),p,k)
% plot(sum(m,2),'.')
plot(m,'.k')

subplot(3,1,3)
p=75;
k=floor(length(x)/p);
m=reshape(x(1:p*k),p,k)
% plot(sum(m,2),'.')
plot(m,'.k')
```

If your amplitudes are systematically increasing/decreasing, you'll probably run into variable variance. There are ways of dealing with this such as log-transform and Box-Cox transform.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for a detailed answer. I'm trying to develop an algorithm which can detect fairly subtle vertical streaks in an image - but the difference in intensity of these streaks vary and also the frequency in which they happen. I've tried autocorrelation but found it to have a false positives with data without streaks. I've not tried spectral analysis, so I'll give that a try. I've also considered wavelet analysis, but without a priori knowledge of the signal - it's hard to judge which wavelet basis I should use. 

I'll give your suggestions a go and see what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeMiller I added a graph with another technique description.

Comment: Thanks Aksakal, this is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Fantastic answer. :)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, and maybe it's worth its own question, but I'm wondering. Let's say that you're testing a data set for seasonality, and you're pretty sure there's a weekly cycle. Is doing a visual analysis of the ACF and noticing peaks at 7, 14, 21 days enough justification? If not, what should be done next?

Comment: @DanielGoldman I rely a lot on visual analysis, but it has many limitations, so the answer is NO, but it's a strong clue. You can run a spectral analysis, and study the spectrogram. Seasonality should show up as peak at its frequency. You can actually use Fourier series (not FFT) to account for seasonality too. There are related filter techniques, where you run a low band pass, then when you subtract the output from series, what's left is a noise and seasonality, so you run another filter with high band pass, and remove noise to get the seasonality alone.

Comment: @Aksakal, what I've done at this point is calculate the Spearman's rank correlation coefficient for the first 14 lags. I used Spearman's because it isn't reasonable to assume normality in the data or lack of outliers. As expected though, the correlation coefficient is relatively high at 7 and 14 days compared to the other lags.

Comment: @DanielGoldman, sometimes you don't need to test anything to know that there's seasonality. For instance, if you're looking at web site traffic, store visits or online retail sales there has to be weekly and annual seasonality plus the holidays.